# how to return [0x01, 0xFF,.....] as string ''01 FF ....' in python

Tags: python, hex

I'm confused about this. how to print hexadecimal bytes:

```
 [0x05, 0x06, 0x40, 0xFD, 0x05]
```

as this in the console:

```
 05 06 40 FD 05
```

And how would I use this in a to_string function:

```
def to_string(bytes):
    cmd = '%02X'.join(chr(b) for b in self.bytes) #does not work obviously
    return cmd

print to_string([0x05, 0x06, 0x40, 0xFD, 0x05])
```

I thought I could generalize from your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `%02X` [string formatter](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
>>> print '%02X' % 0x05
05
>>> for i in [0x05, 0x06, 0x40, 0xFD, 0x05]:
...     print '%02X' % i,
...
05 06 40 FD 05
```

or to make it one string:

```
>>> ' '.join(['%02X' % i for i in [0x05, 0x06, 0x40, 0xFD, 0x05]])
'05 06 40 FD 05'
```

Comment: i thought i could generalize from your answer, but i'm still confused

Answer (score 0):

Martijn's answer is the right answer, but here are some related functions you may not be familiar with.

With the python `format` string operator:

```
>>> for i in [0x05, 0x06, 0x40, 0xFD, 0x05]:
...     print "{:02X}".format(i),
...
05 06 40 FD 05
```

If you actually had the data as bytestrings you could use `binascii.hexlify` to do the same.

```
>>> import binascii
>>> data = ["\x05", "\x06", "\x40", "\xFD", "\x05"]
>>> for d in data:
...     print binascii.hexlify(d),
...
05 06 40 fd 05
```

You could also use the builtin `hex()` with your existing data if you don't mind the data not being padded.

```
>>> data = [0x05, 0x06, 0x40, 0xFD, 0x05]
>>> for i in data:
...     print hex(i),
...
0x5 0x6 0x40 0xfd 0x5
>>>
>>>
>>> # Or use the slice operator to cut off the initial "0x"
>>> for i in data:
...     print hex(i)[2:],
...
5 6 40 fd 5
```

Comment: Martijns solution did it for me, but thanks for sharing your thoughts as well!